# Java OpenCV detect and crop circullar/elliptical shapes

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect and crop circullar/elliptical shapes of different sizes.

This is an example of an image I am trying to do the detection and croping.
[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQtS6.jpg)

The result I am trying to get in the aforementioned image is 3 cropped images

looking like this:

[segmented part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb5NU.jpg), [segmented part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e2jO.jpg), [segmented part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSPwl.jpg)

Another image could look like this: [different image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPPmV.jpg)

Just like the previous image, I am trying to do the same to this one.
The shapes are dramatically smaller from the first one.

Can this be achieved algorithmically or should I look for a machine learning-like solution?

Note: The final image has been applied by the following filters: Gaussian Blur, Grayscale, Threshold, Contour and Morphological Dilation.

[EDIT]

The code I have written(not working as intended):

findReference() finds a shape in the middle of the image and returns its rectangle.

```
    private Rect findReference(Mat inputImage) {
        // clone the image
        Mat original = inputImage.clone();

        // find the center of the image
        double[] centers = {(double)inputImage.width()/2, (double)inputImage.height()/2};
        Point image_center = new Point(centers);

        // finding the contours
        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(inputImage, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        // finding best bounding rectangle for a contour whose distance is closer to the image center that other ones
        double d_min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Rect rect_min = new Rect();

        for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
            Rect rec = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);

            // find the best candidates
            if (rec.height > inputImage.height()/2 & rec.width > inputImage.width()/2){
                continue;
            }

            Point pt1 = new Point((double)rec.x, (double)rec.y);
            Point center = new Point(rec.x+(double)(rec.width)/2, rec.y + (double)(rec.height)/2);
            double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)(pt1.x-image_center.x),2) + Math.pow((double)(pt1.y -image_center.y), 2));
            if (d < d_min)
            {
                d_min = d;
                rect_min = rec;
            }

        }
//        showReference( rect_min, original);

        return rect_min;
    }
```

I use the rectangle as reference and create a bigger one and a smaller one, so that similar shapes fit in the dimensions of the smaller and bigger rectangle.

findAllEllipses() tries to find similar shapes fitting in the smaller and bigger rectangles. After that it draws ellipses around the found shapes.

```
private Mat findAllEllipses(Rect referenceRect, Mat inputImage) {
        float per = 0.5f;
        float perSquare = 0.05f;

        Rect biggerRect = new Rect();
        Rect smallerRect = new Rect();

        biggerRect.width = (int) (referenceRect.width / per);
        biggerRect.height = (int) (referenceRect.height / per);

        smallerRect.width = (int) (referenceRect.width * per);
        smallerRect.height = (int) (referenceRect.height * per);

        System.out.println("reference rectangle height: " + referenceRect.height + " width: " + referenceRect.width);
        System.out.println("[" + 0 +"]: biggerRect.height: " + biggerRect.height + " biggerRect.width: " + biggerRect.width);
        System.out.println("[" + 0 +"]: smallerRect.height: " + smallerRect.height + " smallerRect.width: " + smallerRect.width);

        //Finding Contours
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchey = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(inputImage, contours, hierarchey, Imgproc.RETR_TREE,
                Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        System.out.println("the numbers of found contours is: " + contours.size());
        int sum = 0;
        //Empty rectangle
        RotatedRect[] rec = new RotatedRect[contours.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            rec[i] = new RotatedRect();
            if(contours.get(i).toArray().length >= 5 ){
                Rect foundRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
//                Rect foundBigger = new Rect();
//                Rect foundSmaller = new Rect();
//
//                foundBigger.width = (int) (foundBigger.width + foundBigger.width * per);
//                foundBigger.height = (int) (foundBigger.height + foundBigger.height * per);
//
//                foundSmaller.width = (int) (foundRect.width - foundRect.width * per);
//                foundSmaller.height = (int) (foundRect.height - foundRect.height * per);
                if (
                         (biggerRect.height >= foundRect.height && biggerRect.width >= foundRect.width)
                         && (smallerRect.height <= foundRect.height && smallerRect.width <= foundRect.width)
                         && (((foundRect.width - foundRect.width * perSquare) <= foundRect.height) && ((foundRect.width + foundRect.width * perSquare) >= foundRect.height))
                         && (((foundRect.height - foundRect.height * perSquare) <= foundRect.width) && ((foundRect.height + foundRect.height * perSquare) >= foundRect.width))
                ) {

                    System.out.println("[" + i +"]: foundRect.width: " + foundRect.width + " foundRect.height: " + foundRect.height);
                    System.out.println("----------------");
                    rec[i] = Imgproc.fitEllipse(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray()));
                    sum++;
                }
            }

            Scalar color_elli = new Scalar(190, 0, 0);
            Imgproc.ellipse(inputImage, rec[i], color_elli, 5);
        }
        System.out.println("found ellipses: " + sum);

//        trytest(ImageUtils.doResizeMat(outputImage),0,0);
        return inputImage;
    }
```

Unfortuantelly there are several variables that are hardcoded into the method.

This is used to make the smaller and bigger rectangles (used as a percentage)

```
float per = 0.5f;
```

perSquare is used to get shapes closer to a square (fluctuated width height)

```
float perSquare = 0.05f;
```

This code might work in some images, while on others will not find a single shape, like I mentioned the shapes are circullar/elliptical and of different sizes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65526366/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: have you tried opencv's  HoughCircles() function? I have no experience with java code unfortunately, but I've used the function in python before to mark circles. I don't know if it can be modified to detect ellipses.

Comment: actually: are you looking specifically for circles/ellipses and ignoring all other shapes, or just for any closed shape inside the petri dish?

Comment: Something along those lines, there can be shapes that closely resemble a Reuleaux triangle, Hough circles() won't do unfortunately